# Pandas groupby and mean of a String

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a sample DF:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,size=(6,3)),columns = list("ABC"))
df["A"] = ["1111","2222","1111","1111","2222","1111"]
df["B"] = ["20010101","20010101","20010101","20010101","20010201","20010201"]
df
```

OP:

```
      A       B         C
0   1111    20010101    1
1   2222    20010101    8
2   1111    20010101    1
3   1111    20010101    3
4   2222    20010201    7
5   1111    20010201    8
```

I am trying to find the mean of column B, with grouby of column A:

For example:

consider value "1111" in column A : total transactions : 4, unique transactions : 2 (20010101,20010201). so the mean is 4/2 = 2

Snippet:

```
df.groupby("A",as_index=False).agg({"B":'mean'})
```

Error:

```
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

Any pandas way to find this mean directly instead of doing a groupby and iterating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what you're looking for is the "mean". Try this:

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(lambda x: x.count() / x.nunique())

A
1111    2.0
2222    1.0
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

Or, if you're particular about not using apply, then

```
grp = df.groupby('A')['B']
grp.count() / grp.nunique()

A
1111    2.0
2222    1.0
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

And here's a one liner for the one above, this one uses `agg` with many reducers:

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].agg(['count','nunique']).eval('count / nunique')

A
1111    2.0
2222    1.0
dtype: float64
```